# Is there easy way to verify two dlls equality?

Tags: .net

I have 2 dlls and 2 pdbs.

I want to verify their equality. 
Meaning they have the same content (no nessesarly same creation date)

Is there any easy freeware tool to do so?

Comment: would you care to tell us what you consider "equal"? Same size? Made up of the exact same sequence of bytes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to compare files to ensure the are identical is to you the file compare tool that comes with Windows. From the command window

```
fc /b file1 file2
```

Answer (score 2):

If by *equality* you mean same contents, you could calculate the [SHA1 checksum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha1cryptoserviceprovider.aspx) of both files and compare the two hashes:

```
using(var cryptoProvider = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider())
{
    byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes("library1.dll");
    string hash = BitConverter.ToString(cryptoProvider.ComputeHash(buffer));
}
```

Comment: @EladBenda, why is your question tagged with the `.net` tag? Why is your question asked on StackOverflow if you are not looking for a code solution?